# I have written a Java code for RSA encryption and decryption where the decryption key is too large so the decryption process takes forever to execute

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have to use p=78511 and q= 5657 as per my requirement of the program, the code executes without errors but I as the value of dec_key is too large, it does not display the decrypted text, keeps on running. How do I solve this? Is there a way to have smaller dec_key or am I doing the decryption method all wrong. Here I am trying to pass a character "H" in the encryption method for now.
Attaching the code.
Please do not block my question. I am new here and not so sure how to ask questions, just let me know where I am wrong. Thanks!

```
package crypto.assgn4;  
import static crypto.assgn4.Problem2.phi;
import java.math.BigInteger;
class Test {

static char[] characters = {' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
static BigInteger p = BigInteger.valueOf(78511);
static BigInteger q = BigInteger.valueOf(5657);
static BigInteger N = p.multiply(q);
static BigInteger phi = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
static BigInteger e = BigInteger.ZERO, d;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    e = new BigInteger("4");
    while ((gcd(phi, e).intValue()>1)) {
        e = e.add(new BigInteger("1"));
    }

    d = BigInteger.valueOf(mul_inverse(e, phi));
    if (d.equals(e)) {
        d.add(phi);
    }

    System.out.println("Encryption Key : "+e);
    System.out.println("Decryption Key : "+d);

    String c = encrypt("H",e,N);
    String p = decrypt(c,d,N);

    System.out.println("Cipher : "+c);
    System.out.println("Text : " +p);


}

public static BigInteger gcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    while (b != BigInteger.ZERO) {
        BigInteger temp = b;
        b = a.mod(b);
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}


public static int mul_inverse(BigInteger number, BigInteger sizeOfAlphabet) {
    int a = number.intValue() % sizeOfAlphabet.intValue();
    for (int x = 1; x < sizeOfAlphabet.intValue(); x++) {
        if ((a * x) % sizeOfAlphabet.intValue() == 1) {
            return getMod(x, sizeOfAlphabet.intValue());
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


public static int getMod(int x, int y) {
    int result = x % y;
    if (result < 0) {
        result += y;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * ********************************************************************************
 */
static String encrypt(String plainText, BigInteger e, BigInteger N) {
    StringBuilder cipherText = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
        int index = plainText.charAt(i);
        cipherText.append("").append((char) (new BigInteger(index + "").pow(e.intValue()).mod(N).intValue()));
        char c1 = (char) (new BigInteger(index + "").intValue());
    }
    return cipherText.toString();
}

static String decrypt(String cipherText, BigInteger d, BigInteger N) {

    String plainText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.length(); i++) {
        int index = cipherText.charAt(i);
        plainText += "" + (char) (new BigInteger(index + "").pow(d.intValue()).mod(N).intValue());

    }
    return plainText;
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you use `.intValue()` at all? It does nothing for you except make your code less correct and harder to read.

Comment: (1) Your `mul_inverse` is millions of times slower than necessary; also in general multiplying 29-bit numbers won't fit in Java `int` but your e is always small so this probably doesn't hit
(2) You don't need to convert `int` to decimal `String` on the way to `BigInteger`, just use `BigInteger.valueOf(int)` 
(3) Especially for d, doing `BigInteger.pow` to completion _then_ `mod` takes _much_ longer than the optimized combination `modPow` 
(4) Your code would never finish for RSA sizes that offered any security at all
(5) see comment on answer re `char`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing the encryption/decryption all wrong.

The point of RSA is to take the entire bit pattern of the encoding of the String, and treat that as if it were a BigNumber (e.g. BigInteger) in its own right.  (Note : if that BigNumber is > the modulo then the string has to be chunked in portions such that the BigNumber becomes < the modulo.)

What you are doing on a character by character basis is unnecessary overkill, probably plain wrong as well and *obviously* the source of long running times. (Encrypting your single-character string might still go well because even on a character-by-character basis you'll do only one encryption.  But it will yield a string of length x and then the decryption will do x BigInteger computations and that will inevitably take longer.)

Comment: Actually RSA is rarely used for direct data and normally used in 'hybrid' mode to encrypt only a nonce key which is used to symmetrically encrypt (and decrypt) the data. And RSA encryption must use random padding to prevent an adversary simply guessing, or here finding dupes. Both of those are well covered in wikipedia. But OP actually tries to encrypt each `char` (in `int`) to _one_ `char`, which won't work at all for 29-bit N.